# Spring boot with thymeleaf, strings in list displaying

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try to display list of strings in my spring boot + thymeleaf app.
I have `User` class with `private List<String> opinions` field. I have in memory repository, where I add few strings to user instance and then i try to display my `strings` like this:

```
<ul th:each="opinion : ${user.opinions}">
    <li>
        <span th:text="${opinion}">txt</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I dont know whats wrong because in other class I have also list of `User` and when I display them in same way it works.

**User.java**

```
public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private Integer age;
    private List<String> opinions = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Rating rating;

    public List<String> getOpinions(){
        return this.opinions;
    }

    public void setOpinions(List<String> opinions){
        this.opinions = opinions;
    }
}
```

In memory repository constructor I do like this:

```
User u1 = new User();
List<String> ops = new ArrayList<String>();
    ops.add("123");
    ops.add("456");
u1.setOpinions(ops);
```

Comment: nothing wrong with this html code. Please add more code related to how you get your opinions

Comment: just added more code

Comment: Add code from your controller.

Comment: What do you want for you output? a list of options, like 123 and 456? Why did you put the `txt` in your `span`? Do you want to concat with the options value?

Comment: Make sure you do `model.addAttribute("user", u1);` in your controller.